# Powershell: How to pass Boolean Value into Function Parameter?

Tags: powershell

I've created a function in Powershell and want to pass the Parameter `-Foo` as a Boolean.

I've simplified my Use-Case for Visualization:

```
function Get-Foobar {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [bool]$Foo
    )

    if ($Foo) {
        Write-Host "Foo!"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Bar!"
    }
}
```

The function works as expected, when I call the function `Get-Foobar -Foo $true`. But this is not what I want. Just `Get-Foobar -Foo` should suffice.

[Referring to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#parameter-attribute), specifying the parameter when calling the function should already return a true. But apparently this does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the **Switch parameter**:

> Switch parameters are parameters with no parameter value.
> [Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#switch-parameters)

Example:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [Switch]
    $Foo
)
```

Comment: Awesome, but weired. I always thought, a Boolean expression behaves like a switch.